# Python: using regex and while loop to break out paragraphs in a PDF

Tags: python, regex

I have a pdf file that has 82 paragraphs, my goal is to use python to break each paragraph into its own block of text. I have already extracted the text using PyPDF2.

The paragraphs all begin with a number and a period (1. 42. 76. etc.). It is working for most of the paragraphs with the code below, but it doesn't always take the period into account. For example, number 18's match output is: "18 (06/". This shouldn't have gotten picked up though because there isn't a period after it. Any suggestions?

Code for finding positions:

```
i = 1
all_positions = []
found = "found"

while found == "found":
    matches = []
    matches_positions =[]
    standard_length = 0
    substring = str(i) + "."
    matches = re.finditer(substring, text, re.IGNORECASE)
    matches_positions = [match.start() for match in matches]
    standard_length = len(matches_positions)
    if standard_length > 0:
        all_positions.append(matches_positions[0])
        i += 1
    else:
        found = "not found"
```

Code for printing output:

```
for i in range(0,len(all_positions)):
     print('---')
     print(text[all_positions[i]:all_positions[i+1]])
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the text to the question? I think you are using a number plus a dot as the substring which will turn into a regex that matches a digit followed by any character except a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below regex to achieve your result:

```
^\d+\. ?(.*)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`^`** - Represents the start of the given test String.
>
> **`\d+`** - Matches digits[0-9] one or more times.
>
> **`\.`** - Matches dot **literally.**
>
> **`?`** - Represents zero or one space character.
>
> **`(.*)`** - Represents capturing group capturing the paragraph text greedily.

You can find the regex demo [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/7g9UwJ/5)

**IMPLEMENTATION IN PYTHON:**

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"^\d+\. ?(.*)", re.MULTILINE)
match = pattern.findall("1. Hellow World\n"
    "23. This is loremIpsum text\n"
    "9001. Some random textbcjsbcskcbksck sbcksbcksckscsk\n"
    "90 (89. Some other") 
print (match)
# Output - ['Hellow World', 'This is loremIpsum text', 'Some random textbcjsbcskcbksck sbcksbcksckscsk']
```

You can find the implementation of the above code [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/By8LZbCiL)

Comment: You can omit the lazy part `?` matching the digits, as matching the digits can not cross the dot itself.

Comment: Thanks for the same @Thefourthbird. Updated the same.